# MLE error in R: non-finite finite-difference value/ value in 'vmmin' is not finite

Tags: r, optimization, logistic-regression, infinite, mle

I am working on a loss aversion model in R (beginner) and want to estimate some parameters, from a dataset with 3 columns (loss/gain values (both continous and a column with decisions coded as 0 or 1 (binary)) 
dropbox.com/s/fpw3obrqcx8ld1q/GrandAverage.RData?dl=0 
The part of the code if have to use for this I am using is given below:

```
set <- GrandAverage[, 5:7];
  Beh.Parameters <- function (lambda, alpha, temp) {
 u = 0.5 * set$Gain^alpha + 0.5 * lambda * set$Loss^alpha
  GambleProbability <- 1 / (1 + exp(-temp * u))

  loglike <- set$Decision*log(GambleProbability) + 
    (1- set$Decision)*log(1-GambleProbability)   

  return(-sum(loglike))
 }

  temp_s <- 0.1 #runif(1, 0.1, 1)

  ML.estim1  <- mle(Beh.Parameters, start = list (lambda = 1, alpha = 1, temp = temp_s), nobs = length(set$Decision))
  ML.estim2  <- mle(Beh.Parameters, start = list(lambda = 0.1, alpha = 0.1,  temp = temp_s), nobs = length(set$Decision))
```

I use the mle function in order to estimate the 3 parameters (lambda, alpha and temp), without the alpha i receive this output for example:

> ML.estim1
>   Call:
>   mle(minuslogl = Beh.Parameters, start = list(lambda = 1, temp = temp_s), 
>       nobs = length(set$Decision))
>   Coefficients:
>     lambda     temp 
>   1.298023 1.041057

When I try to run it without the alpha parameter it works fine but when I include it I received these two errors:

> Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) :
>   non-finite finite-difference value [2] (for the first MLE) Error in
>   optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) :    initial
>   value in 'vmmin' is not finite (for the second MLE)

I tried to recode the matrix, singular value decomposition, BFGS etc. 
Any help is welcome...thanks in advance.

Comment: Your dropbox link doesn't work

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fpw3obrqcx8ld1q/GrandAverage.RData?dl=0

Comment: my bad... and now?

Comment: Fixed (but you should update your question)

Comment: Where does the `mle` function come from?

Comment: i use the mle to estimate the parameters (Beh.parameters)...should i use it differently?

Comment: @cgillespie `stats4::mle`

Answer (score 2):

Your `Loss` variable is negative. In R, raising negative values to a fractional power (i.e. `set$Loss^alpha` where `alpha` is non-integer) returns `NaN` values. (The only general alternative is to return a complex-valued answer, which you probably don't want.)  Did you mean to code `Loss` as positive rather than negative? Or maybe you want `-abs(set$Loss^alpha)` ?

As a general purpose debugging tip, it helps to add

```
cat(lambda,alpha,temp,-sum(loglike),"\n")
```

as the second-to-last-line of your objective function so you can better see what's going on.

Comment: @ Ben Bolker thanks havent thought of it.. dunno whether recoding the loss variable makes sense but ill give it a try

Comment: still no correct output...-abs(set$Loss^alpha) seems to produce the same error.. is there a way to transform both positive/negative variables in the positive domain or something like that?