# Correct usage of stats4::mle

Tags: r, mle

I want to use stats4::mle function to estimate the best parameters (2) of a distribution.

I would like to be sure my usage is correct and get guidance to avoid error

> "Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
>     initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In log(mu) : NaNs produced"

Function I would like to estimate is exp(beta0*a + beta1*b) and I would like to estimate the betas

Sample code:

```
a <- mydata$a # first variable
b <- mydata$b # second variable
y <- mydata$y # observed result

nll <- function(beta0, beta1) {
mu = y - exp(beta0 * a + beta1 * b)
- sum(log(mu))
}

est <- stats4::mle(minuslog = nll, start = list(beta0 = 0.0001, beta1 = 0.0001))
est
```

So:

- Is this the correct way of doing things?
- For the error, I understand this is due to values of mu getting to 0, but I don't know what I can do with it

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Read here perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485247/mle-error-in-r-non-finite-finite-difference-value-value-in-vmmin-is-not-fini?rq=1

Comment: Yes seems somewhat related, and my second question in the last question in that thread but no one seems to have the answer. Sadly. Thanks anyway.